# ORDER_BY value within nested query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm currently getting my expected output but I'm looking to now order the query by `skill_match` but unsure how to order the current query by `skill_match`. `skill_match` exists within a nested query.

My question is how would I go about ordering the following query by `skill_match`

```
$matches = $this->db->query("

        SELECT *
        FROM
        (SELECT job_string, jobseeker_string, requirement_type,
              count(1) / (SELECT count(1) FROM employer_requirements WHERE jobseeker_string = j.jobseeker_string AND requirement_type = 'e' ) AS skill_match
            FROM employer_requirements r
            INNER JOIN jobseeker_skills j
            ON r.skill_string = j.skill_string
            GROUP BY job_string, jobseeker_string) t
        LEFT JOIN users u
        ON t.jobseeker_string = u.string                 
        INNER JOIN applications a
        on t.job_string = a.job_string and t.jobseeker_string = a.jobseeker_string      
        WHERE a.job_string = '".$str."'
        ORDER_BY r.skill_match          

");


return $matches;
```

I get the following output when I do a `print_r()` and want to `ORDER_BY skill_match` value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [job_string] => G2vJhXNUquRELfxQ
        [jobseeker_string] => ltyjBhtbHn5knsht
        [requirement_type] => e
        [skill_match] => 0.2000
        [id] => 1
        [user_level] => 3
        [name] => Steve
        [email] => something@hotmail.com
        [password] => 3b8751e0f3f81ea085329e44d1d28f2e105f4031efd02ff7430c05d88ce90dcbacaef2f4239882e784b3d133d8aadc88404e670b284b95ab6963b58d00a6b864
        [score] => 116
        [string] => ltyjBhtbHn5knsht
        [date_created] => 2014-04-15 12:16:13
        [employer_string] => sm4jBhtbv13knsht
        [application_string] => bX0JOwUnhsKEQaAq
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [job_string] => G2vJhXNUquRELfxQ
        [jobseeker_string] => qThkM0OIKVUukp6J
        [requirement_type] => e
        [skill_match] => 0.4000
        [id] => 2
        [user_level] => 3
        [name] => Bruce
        [email] => someone@gmail.com
        [password] => 3b8751e0f3f81ea085329e44d1d28f2e105f4031efd02ff7430c05d88ce90dcbacaef2f4239882e784b3d133d8aadc88404e670b284b95ab6963b58d00a6b864
        [score] => 116
        [string] => qThkM0OIKVUukp6J
        [date_created] => 2014-04-15 12:16:13
        [employer_string] => sm4jBhtbv13knsht
        [application_string] => bX0JOwUnhsKEQaAq
    )

)
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be not `ORDER_BY r.skill_match`, but `ORDER BY t.skill_match` instead.

Comment: I've already tried a few iterations on `ORDER_BY r.skill_match`, `ORDER_BY t.skill_match` and `ORDER_BY skill_match`. Throws the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER_BY t.skill_match' at line 14`

Comment: @learn the correct term is `ORDER BY` not `ORDER_BY` without **underscore _**

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid How very stupid of me, I don't know why I was adding the underscore. Thanks guys that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The ORDER BY without undercore (_)

```
$matches = $this->db->query("

            SELECT *
            FROM
            (SELECT job_string, jobseeker_string, requirement_type,
                  count(1) / (SELECT count(1) FROM employer_requirements WHERE jobseeker_string = j.jobseeker_string AND requirement_type = 'e' ) AS skill_match
                FROM employer_requirements r
                INNER JOIN jobseeker_skills j
                ON r.skill_string = j.skill_string
                GROUP BY job_string, jobseeker_string) t
            LEFT JOIN users u
            ON t.jobseeker_string = u.string                 
            INNER JOIN applications a
            on t.job_string = a.job_string and t.jobseeker_string = a.jobseeker_string      
            WHERE a.job_string = '".$str."'
            ORDER BY r.skill_match          

    ");


    return $matches;
```